# Oracle SQL trigger on update issue - Study / learnings

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have created a copy of an existing database (I_Customer) with the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE N_CUSTOMER AS SELECT * FROM I_CUSTOMER;
```

I have created the below table that will act as a log for modifications to the N_Customer table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_CHANGELOG 
( cust_no NUMBER(5),
cust_name VARCHAR2(20),
contact VARCHAR2(20),
log_date DATE);
```

I have also created (with help from a stack member) the below trigger that will fire after the N_Customer table is edited and write some specific fields (new and old) tot he Customer_Changelog table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER customer_up_tr
AFTER UPDATE ON n_customer
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.contact <> 1 AND NEW.contact = 1 OR OLD.cust_name <> 1 AND NEW.cust_name = 1)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO customer_changelog (cust_no, cust_name, contact, log_date) VALUES (:OLD.cust_no, :OLD.cust_name, :OLD.contact, sysdate);
      INSERT INTO customer_changelog (cust_no, cust_name, contact, log_date) VALUES (:NEW.cust_no, :NEW.cust_name, :NEW.contact, sysdate);
END;
```

Now when I use the below code to edit the N_Customer table:

```
UPDATE N_CUSTOMER
SET cust_name = 'Peter Davis', contact = 'Sam Bogdanovich'
WHERE cust_no = 2338;
```

I get this error:

```
UPDATE N_CUSTOMER
*
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Now my data types etc all match so I am not sure what could be causing this.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are cust_name and contact (used in the WHEN clause) numeric?

Comment: Hi Ron.  No they are VARCHAR2(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line of the trigger:

```
(OLD.contact <> 1 AND NEW.contact = 1 OR OLD.cust_name <> 1 AND NEW.cust_name = 1)
```

Contact and cust_name fields are VARCHAR2, but the trigger is comparing them to a number.

This simple example will fail with the same error:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
WHERE 'abc' <> 1;
```

Comment: Hi Shawn.  So do I literally replace the 1 with abc?

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.  If I just remove WHEN {(OLD.contact <> 1 AND NEW.contact = 1 OR OLD.cust_name <> 1 AND NEW.cust_name = 1)} the trigger does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `OLD.contact <> 1` is comparing the character column `contact` to a number (This is also known as "comparing apples to oranges").

Because the conversion of a number to a character is ambigous (it could be converted to `'01',`'001'`...) Oracle will do it the other way round and convert the character value to a number (because that is non-amgigous`'01'`,`'001'`will both result in the number`1`).

You apparently have non-numeric values in the `contact` column (which is to be expected based on the column's name and it's data type)  the conversion fails.

The simple rule is:

### Never rely on implicit type casting

Use character literals for characters and number literals for numbers. `1` is a number. `'1'` is a character literal.

Having said all that, you need to change this line:

```
OLD.contact <> 1 AND NEW.contact = 1 OR OLD.cust_name <> 1 AND NEW.cust_name = 1
```

to

```
OLD.contact <> '1' AND NEW.contact = '1' OR OLD.cust_name <> '1' AND NEW.cust_name = '1'
```